# Retrieve all essential data on startup

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee

In Java Web Application, i would like to know if it is a proper (or "standard"?) way that all the essential data such as the config data, message data, code maintenance data, dropdown option data and etc (assuming all data will not updated frequently) are loaded as a "static" variables from database when the server startup.
Or is it more preferred way to retrieve data by querying db per request?

Thanks for all your advice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly valid to pull out all the data that are not going to be modified during application life-cycle into and keep it in memory as singleton or something.

This is a good idea because it saves DB hits and retrieval is faster. A lot of environment specific settings and other data can also be pulled once and kept in an immutable hashmap for any future request.

In a common web-app you generally do not have so many config data/option objects that can eat up lot of memory and cause OOM. But, if you have a table with hundreds of thousands of config data, better assume pulling objects as and when requested. And if you *do* want to keep it in memory, think of putting this in some key-value store like MemcacheD.

Comment: Will the memory be the only concern in this approach?<br>As I am afraid of *OutOfMemory* if those tables keep growth in the future.

Comment: @Cube Consider how may tables and how many rows will you have as config. Lets say, You have `3000`, config objects each with `10` string fields each string with `1000` char. You will be taking `30MB` -- which is not much. Even if your data grow 10 times `30K` config objects, you will be eating up `300MB` which is not high on webserver given the efficiently you get out of it. But, 30K config objects are not realistic. If you have a lot of config setting consider using MemcahceD for config object storage.

Answer (score 0):

We used DB to store config values and ehcache to avoid a lot of DB hits. This way you don't need to worry about memory consumption (it will use whatever memory you have).

EhCache is one of many available DB cache solution and can be configured on top of JPA etc.

You can configure ehcache (or many other cache providers) to deem the tables read-only, in which case it will only go to the DB if it's explicitly told to invalidate the cache. This performs pretty well. The overhead becomes visible though when the read occurs very frequently (like 100/sec), but usually storing the config value in a local variable and avoiding reading inside loops, passing it on through the method stack during the invocation mitigates this well enough.

Storing values in a Singleton as java objects performs the best, but if you want to modify these without app. start up, it becomes a little bit involved.

Here is a simple way to achieve dynamic configuration with Java objects:

```
private volatile ImmutableMap<String,Object> param_value
```

Basically you'll have to start thinking about multi-threaded access, and memory issues (while it's quite unlikely that you'll run out of memory because of configuration values, unless you have binary data as config values etc.).

In essence, I'd recommend using the DB and some cache provider unless that part of code  really needs high-performance.

Comment: Thanks for your introduction of EhCache and "dynamic configuration with Java objects", i will go through them in detail later. :)